How to get environment name in Program.cs file in .NET 8?
I am trying to add appsettings.json file for different environments. How do I get environment name in program.cs in .NET 8 that looks like this:
var options = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                     .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
#if DEBUG
                     .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
#else
                     .AddJsonFile("appsettings(pass the env name).json")
 #endif
                     .Build();

 var host = new HostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                    .ConfigureServices(services =>
                        {
                            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                            services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
                        })
                    .Build();
host.Run();

There are several posts here, but none of those are recognized in .NET 8, most are for .NET 6.

From Properties -> launchSetting.json we can get the Environment name.
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", true, true)
.Build();

Please check out my git repo: https://github.com/rezaulk/StackOverflow/tree/master/Q.78800876
I made a console app for this question using .NET 8.


I am trying to add appsettings.json file for different environments.
How do I get environment name in program.cs in .NET 8. How to get
environment name in Program.cs file in .NET 8?

In .NET 8, you can use the IHostEnvironment interface to get the environment name in the Program.cs file. You can modify your configuration to load the appropriate appsettings.json file based on the current environment.
So if you would like to set multiple environments you could do as following:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
}

Output:

However, if you would like to read any specific environment variable and its value, you could try as following:

string[] specificVariables = { "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "MyCustomEnvVar1", "MyCustomEnvVar2" };
foreach (var variable in specificVariables)
{
    var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variable);
    if (value != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{variable} = {value}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{variable} is not set");
    }
}

Output:


Note: Please refer to this official document, if you need additional details.
